# Node.js Express 4 modular routing issues

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local, express-4

I've been wrestling with modularizing my node.js express app, I would like each part in it own directory, but cannot seem to get the routing right.

each is in for example app/lib/main main being the index which loads fine
just not /login or /notes

the console throws me this but have no view directory

Error: Failed to lookup view "login.ejs" in views directory "/home/dave/node/app/views"

### at Function.app.render

GET /login 500 54ms - 1.01kb

currently the app.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var login = require('./lib/login');
var main = require('./lib/main');
var notes = require('./lib/notes');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets/css', { maxAge: oneDay }));// load the       folder

app.use(main);
app.use(login);
app.use(notes);

app.listen(config.server.port);
console.log('server listening on port 3000')
```

is this default behaviour? As i can seem to find any info on the node.js or express website

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to section off your routes. (http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router)

```
app.use('/', main);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/notes', notes);
```

I have a similar style of sectioning off parts of my site behind routes, though I section everything within the root "routes" directory. You can see how I've done things if it helps: https://github.com/codetunnel/pawproject/blob/master/app.js#L63-L65

In express 4 the pattern is to create a new router for every area. Usually they assign `module.exports = router` at the bottom of the file, and that's what you're passing to `app.use`. Since you're leaving out the URL pattern that router should operate under I'm guessing that's why the first one works and the rest fail to override the router already specified at root.

I'm new to Express 4 and still getting used to the changes so I may not be 100% correct, but I believe that's the issue your'e having as I had a similar problem. I'll keep poking around though :)